# Spark Accumulator value when the spark context is reading a folder with 100 files?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, accumulator

Spark program to count the accumulator value which is initialized at 0 and is going to be incremented by 1, when the program is reading a folder with 100 files?

```
val myaccumulator = sc.accumulator(0)
val inputRDD= sc.wholeTextFiles("/path/to/100Files")
inputRDD.foreach(f => myaccumulator + f.count)

<console>:29: error: value count is not a member of (String, String)
   inputRDD.foreach(f => myaccumulator + f.count)
                                 ^
```

Comment: scala> inputRDD.foreach(f => myAcc + 1)
<console>:29: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
       inputRDD.foreach(f => myAcc + 1)

Comment: Did you try `myacc.add(1)` ?

Comment: Yeah changing to "myacc.add(1)" to worked but the accumulator value doesn't change with respect to number of partitions passed as parameter to wholeTextFiles("path/to/100/files",20). Ideally the accumulator value should change based on the number of partitions and cores. But here it stays 100(since there are 100 files) always.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the lines in your files, you don't need anything fancy. This would do:

```
sc.textFile("path/to/dir/containing/the/files").count
```

If you absolutely want to use an accumulator, you can do it this way:

```
val myaccumulator = sc.accumulator(0)
sc.textFile("path/to/dir/containing/the/files").foreach(_ => myaccumulator += 1)
```

If you absolutely want to use wholeTextFile (which puts the **whole** content of each file in a single String), any of the following would count the lines:

```
sc.wholetextFiles("path/to/dir/containing/the/files")
    .map(_._2.split("\\n").size)
    .reduce(_+_)
```

or with an accumulator

```
val myaccumulator = sc.accumulator(0)
sc.wholeTextFiles
    .foreach(x => myaccumulator += x._2.split("\\n").size)
```